# How to add data to a specific form element when it sends to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm creating a form where people can enter a code, for example H23J3PW, which corresponds to the end of a URL (say for example's sake youtube.com/watch?=H23J3PW)

When the database is submitted to the database I'd like it to submit as the full URL ie "youtube.com/watch?=H23J3PW". Is there an easy way to do this?

The form code at the moment is:

```
<label>youtube.com/</label><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="youtube" value=""/>
```

Thanks in advance, I have searched around but haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?=".$_POST["youtube"];
```

Then just use $url in your query.  As mentioned in the comment, $_POST could be $_GET if your form is submitted using a GET.

Comment: Its actually $_GET['youtube']; because its not on POST (asuming the <form> is with GET method.)

Comment: Typically, on Stack Overflow, when you find that someone has answered your question, you click the check mark beside the answer to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that somehow. Done.